# Populate a Select HTML element from JSON parsed object array

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JSON data and I want to populate an html select element from it, please I don't see how to use a for each loop with such a json data. Thanks.

//JSON

```
[{
    "group": "US (Common)",
    "zones": [{
        "value": "America/Puerto_Rico",
        "name": "Puerto Rico (Atlantic)"
    }, {
        "value": "Pacific/Honolulu",
        "name": "Honolulu (Hawaii)"
    }]
}, {
    "group": "Africa",
    "zones": [{
        "value": "Africa/Tunis",
        "name": "Tunis"
    }, {
        "value": "Africa/Windhoek",
        "name": "Windhoek"
    }]
}]
```

and the html select element looks like :

```
<select id="timeZones"></select>
```

and this is JS code that is not working :

```
var $select = $('#timeZones');
$.ajax({
    url: 'timezones.json',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            $select.append('<OPTGROUP LABEL="' + val[i].group + '"><OPTION VALUE="' + val[i].zone[i].value + '">' + val[i].zone[i].name + '</OPTION></OPTGROUP>');
        })
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("JSON ERROR");
    }
});
```

Comment: Where are you getting the json data from?  Or what web framework are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Its easier to do two each functions on nested nodes

```
 success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
        bar = '<OPTGROUP LABEL="' + val.group + '">';      
        $.each(val.zones, function(zoneID,zoneData) {
            bar += '<OPTION VALUE="' + zoneData.value + '">' + zoneData.name + '</OPTION>';  
        });
        bar += '</OPTGROUP>';
        $('#timeZones').append(bar);
   });    

}
```

here is a jsfiddle of the working solution http://jsfiddle.net/hZsQS/132/

However you may want to look at things like jsrender for templating

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer but It did not work, my select element is still empty, I tried some debug by doing as following:                                                                                                                                 var $select = $('#timeZones');
$.ajax({
url: 'timezones.json',
dataType:'JSON',
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
 alert(val.group);
 });
},
error:function(){
alert("JSON ERROR");
}
});

Comment: i just fixed the syntax AGAIN (extra double quote in front of LABEL), sorry bout that, included a jsfiddle just to verify its up to snuff

Comment: really, really OFF day, everything is now fixed in the answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll have to have nested `$.each` loops; one to loop through the groups and add the `<optgroup>`, and the inner loop to loop through the zones and add each `<option>` to the appropriate `<optgroup>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Knockout Framework to map an json String to a select box (very less code).

example:
JavaScript:

```
var json = '{"showFilter":["notStarted","running"],"whatEver":["one","two"]}';
  var model = ko.mapping.fromJSON(json);
  ko.applyBindings(model);
```

HTML:

```
<p>Filter: <select data-bind="options: showFilter"></select></p>
<p>WhatEver: <select data-bind="options: whatEver"></select></p>
```

see also:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html